# Changing size of active window on Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I would like to get active window and change it size on mac os x i.e. safari, xcode or any other

I have already tried:

```
NSWindow *topWindow = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
```

and then setFrame but it did not work.

Comment: Welcome to the site.. what do you mean by "Did not work"?  Did it do something, though not what you were expecting?  Did it give you an error?

Comment: topWindow is alway nil no matter what application is choosen. And when I try to use:
NSRunningApplication *currentApp = [NSRunningApplication currentApplication];
the application name that is return by [currentApp localizedName] is correct.

Comment: You try to change window size of another process ? `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]` return a window of your application. If you want to change size of other process, you need to use AppleScript.

Comment: I try to change window size of another process.
Thanks for the tip with AppleScript i will check it